# JasperReports: CONCATENATE function not found

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports

I'm developing some reports with *Jaspersoft Studio*.
I have a web app that should accept REST queries, and turn them into compiled reports.
So I have some of the *JasperReports* jars included:

- groovy-all-2.0.1.jar
- iText-2.1.7.js2.jar
- jasperreports-5.2.0.jar

Problem is that when I compile my report and run from the *Jaspersoft Studio*, it works fine.
 
But when I compile and run it from my web app, it throws the exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : CONCATENATE($V{startString}, "  -  ", $V{endString})
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:244)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559)
...
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Function CONCATENATE not found
```

When I change my `CONCATENATE` call in the report it works fine.

So this leaves me with a solution that I'm missing one of the *JasperReports* jars, but which one?

Comment: It is one of the Text function (groovy)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should also add *jasperreports-functions-5.2.0.jar* to your classpath.

This library contains *net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.TextFunctions* class with *CONCATENATE* function.

You can find this artifact at http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases *Maven* repository.

The snippet from my test *pom.xml*:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jr-ce-releases</id>
        <url>http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The *net.sf.jasperreports.jasperreports-functions:5.2.0* artifact depends on *joda-time.joda-time:2.1* artifact - you should also add to classpath the *joda-time-2.1.jar*

---

***Notes:***

You can find more information in [Custom Functions in Report Expressions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/functions/index.html) article

Comment: From other recent experience: this question is also very relevant to the date-time functions as well. Maybe someone should try to link date-time function relation questions to this post as well. Trying to use TODAY() or NOW() in JasperStudio will yield the same result without adding these libraries to classpath.

Comment: I had the same issue with the `MONTH()` function, this solution worked for me just adding `jasperreports-functions` and changing `groovy` to `groovy-all`. I don't know if this last was necesary, but my app is running smoothly. Thank you so much @AlexK