# The jrxml file compilation failed due to built-in missing in ant

Tags: ant, jasper-reports

The ant script throws error when compiling the `.jrxml` to `.jasper` file, only for the files which are using the *JasperReports* built-in functions. Please help me to resolve this issue.

The *JasperReports* version is 5.5.2. I've updated the `jasperreports_extension.properties` with

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.functions=net.sf.jasperreports.functions.FunctionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.functions.datetime=net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.DateTimeFunctions
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.functions.math=net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.MathFunctions, net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.LogicalFunctions
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.functions.text=net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.TextFunctions
```

The error trace from the ant build script:

```
 [jrc] File : C:\Projects\JasperReport\src\main\report\Flower.jrxml ... FAILED.
      [jrc] Error compiling report design : C:\Projects\DU\JasperReport\src\main\report\Flower.jrxml
      [jrc] net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
      [jrc] 1. The method DATEFORMAT(Date, String) is undefined for the type Flower_1400575815940_409825
      [jrc]                 value = DATEFORMAT(new Date(((java.sql.Timestamp)field_TIMESHEETDATE.getValue()).getTime()),"MMMM"); //$JR_EXPR_ID=15$
      [jrc]                         <-------->
      [jrc] 2. The method DATEFORMAT(Date, String) is undefined for the type Flower_1400575815940_409825
      [jrc]                 value = DATEFORMAT(new Date(((java.sql.Timestamp)field_TIMESHEETDATE.getOldValue()).getTime()),"MMMM"); //$JR_EXPR_ID=15$
      [jrc]                         <-------->
      [jrc] 3. The method DATEFORMAT(Date, String) is undefined for the type Flower_1400575815940_409825
      [jrc]                 value = DATEFORMAT(new Date(((java.sql.Timestamp)field_TIMESHEETDATE.getValue()).getTime()),"MMMM"); //$JR_EXPR_ID=15$
      [jrc]                         <-------->
      [jrc] 3 errors
      [jrc]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:204)
      [jrc]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:354)
      [jrc]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:270)
      [jrc]     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:252)
      [jrc]     at net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask.compile(JRAntCompileTask.java:402)
      [jrc]     at net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask.execute(JRAntCompileTask.java:249)
      [jrc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
      [jrc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      [jrc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
      [jrc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
      [jrc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
      [jrc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
      [jrc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
      [jrc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
      [jrc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
      [jrc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
      [jrc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
      [jrc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
      [jrc]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
      [jrc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
      [jrc]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
      [jrc]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JasperReports: CONCATENATE function not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450214/jasperreports-concatenate-function-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

The jasperreport 5.5.3 project build doesn't generating the jasper-functions-5.5.2.jar under the dist dir. We need to download the jasper-functions jar manually with joda-time jar as dependency.