# Jasper Studio JRXML compile, how to integrate with java, required jars

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have prepared JRXMl using *Jaspersoft Studio*. I used predefined logical functions like IF. 
When I am trying to Integrate in java, (I want to generate report using JRXML from Java program) I am getting the error below:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method DATEFORMAT(java.util.Date,java.lang.String)
location: class ServiceLevelAnalysis_1407129001044_460064
                value = IF(((java.util.Date)parameter_Fromdate.getValue()).getYear()==0,"Open Invoices",DATEFORMAT(((java.util.Date)parameter_Fromdate.getValue()),"MM/dd/yy")+" - " +DATEFORMAT(((java.util.Date)parameter_ToDate.getValue()),"MM/dd/yy")); //$JR_EXPR_ID=10$
                                                                                                        ^
D:\MSIJasper\MSIJasperDemo\ServiceLevelAnalysis_1407129001044_460064.java:259: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method DATEFORMAT(java.util.Date,java.lang.String)
location: class ServiceLevelAnalysis_1407129001044_460064
                value = IF(((java.util.Date)parameter_Fromdate.getValue()).getYear()==0,"Open Invoices",DATEFORMAT(((java.util.Date)parameter_Fromdate.getValue()),"MM/dd/yy")+" - " +DATEFORMAT(((java.util.Date)parameter_ToDate.getValue()),"MM/dd/yy")); //$JR_EXPR_ID=10$
```

Which jar do I need to add to resolve this?
My code is

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("D:\\JaspersoftStudioWorkspace\\MyReports\\ServiceLevelAnalysis.jrxml");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "D:\\JaspersoftStudioWorkspace\\MyReports\\sample.pdf");
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You will need jasper report api

Comment: @user1323993 Are you using *Groovy* expression? This post can help you: [JasperReports: CONCATENATE function not found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19450214/876298)

Comment: i have solved my problem with jasperreports-functions jar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: CONCATENATE function not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450214/jasperreports-concatenate-function-not-found)