# Jasper string functions method undefined error

Tags: function, jasper-reports

Using Jasper Reports 5.6.1.  Added some text functions to a previously working text field jrxml (just want to truncate if longer than 75 chars).  Works in iReport Studio, but not in Java.

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[IF(LEN($F{AccountName})<75,$F{AccountName},LEFT($F{AccountName},75)+"...")]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Error message:

```
Error occured while trying to fetch the HTML Output from the Jasper     Service (Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The method LEN(String) is undefined for the type ICC_1422636250096_198427
            value = IF(LEN(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()))<75,((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()),LEFT(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()),75)+"..."); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                       <->
2. The method LEFT(String, int) is undefined for the type ICC_1422636250096_198427
            value = IF(LEN(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()))<75,((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()),LEFT(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()),75)+"..."); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                                                                                                                 <-->
3. The method LEN(String) is undefined for the type ICC_1422636250096_198427
            value = IF(LEN(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getOldValue()))<75,((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getOldValue()),LEFT(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getOldValue()),75)+"..."); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                       <->
4. The method LEFT(String, int) is undefined for the type ICC_1422636250096_198427
            value = IF(LEN(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getOldValue()))<75,((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getOldValue()),LEFT(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getOldValue()),75)+"..."); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                                                                                                                       <-->
5. The method LEN(String) is undefined for the type ICC_1422636250096_198427
            value = IF(LEN(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()))<75,((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()),LEFT(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()),75)+"..."); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                       <->
6. The method LEFT(String, int) is undefined for the type ICC_1422636250096_198427
            value = IF(LEN(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()))<75,((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()),LEFT(((java.lang.String)field_AccountName.getValue()),75)+"..."); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                                                                                                                 <-->
6 errors
)
```

I checked packages in jasperreports-5.6.1.jar file, includes functions package.  Exhaustive web search turned up nothing.  What could it be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: CONCATENATE function not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450214/jasperreports-concatenate-function-not-found)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a similar error message. Where you able to resolve this? Works fine in Jaspersoft Studio 6.0.1, but throws this when compiling w/ Java:

The method IF(boolean, BigDecimal, BigDecimal) is undefined for the type Blank_A4_1_1423164610392_674232

**Update**: I was able to solve this by including the functions jar on my classpath. See that if that works for you. See jasperreports-functions-5.6.1.jar at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%205.6.1/

Comment: What the heck. This actually worked. I was having similar issues as well to TC, then I decided to follow this and added the Jasper-Functions dependency (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports-functions/6.20.0) ,in addition to Jasper-Reports and now my reports generates(still have issues, but at least working better then previously)

Answer (score 0):

When using GlassFish, verify that you have all jasper libraries on your production server. They should be under glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext. If the jars are not there (or some of them, such as the fonts or some other not non-requisite lib) you might experience the behavior you are describing.