# Jasper Report IF condition in Text Field Value

Tags: jasper-reports

Using text field value editor i add a text to the text field with a condition (note the if is constructed using the field editor of JasperSoft studio so the code IF(...) is autogenerated, i gave only the value "pippo" and "pluto")

```
"Some value" +IF(true,"pippo","pluto")
```

But it seems it don't work. I'm getting this error during calling the report from my code:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The method IF(boolean, String, String) is undefined for the type
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where (at Java code or at Jaspersoft Studio) did you get this error? Your expression is absolutely right and should work at least for Groovy language (set for report)

Comment: I get the error while trying to generate the report at runtime, expression was created in JasperSoft Studio, report compile fine but did not execute fine.
@Alex may be a duplicate could be this (but i was not able to test the solution no valid maven artifact for jar involve too much work so i change strategy and use expression reported in my comment to solution) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243558/jasper-string-functions-method-undefined-error

Comment: Duplicates: [JasperReports: CONCATENATE function not found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19450214/876298)

Comment: Try to add `net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-functions` artifact

Comment: Thank you @AlexK i cannot test the suggestion because i used the other solution (the one in the answer) , anyway seems a good solution , i wasn't able to found this artifact googling around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `ternary` operator instead of `IF` like below

```
"Some value" + (value == true ? "pippo" : "pluto")
```

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: Missing the == , anyway this save me hour of testing, this is a correct answer
This code work for me: 

`($F{fieldInReport} == true ? "pippo" : "pluto")`. fieldInReport is a boolean field (damn apparently i tested same code yesterday and it did not work :)!). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include **jasperreports-functions** in your build file.
e.g: for gradle

```
implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-functions:6.12.2'
```