# Jasper built-in functions do not work

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm creating reports using Jasper and JasperSoft Studio. It's a maven springboot application.
The reports work good. Also the data connection works as it should.

I only have problems with the built-in functions (like sum(), trim(), replace(), ...). Also I'm not able to write custom functions. When I call one of those functions, an error appears on generating the report. Following the message:

```
1. The method REPLACE(String, int, int, String) is undefined for the type report_1475756642067_881680 
value = REPLACE(((java.lang.String)field1.getValue()),2,5,"test"); //$JR_EXPR_ID=65$
```

All works fine in Jaspersoft studio, the error only appears when I generate the report.

In Jaspersoft Studio all required external libraries are added.
Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What language is set in report (groovy)?

Comment: no, it's java 1.7

Comment: Try to set *groovy* for report's property *language*

Comment: You can also look at [JasperReports: CONCATENATE function not found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19450214/876298) post

Comment: Virtual +1 for Alex K. Had the same problem with iReport. Tried with adding jasperreports-functions-x.x.jar to classpath, but this finally solved it. Might it be an option to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set groovy for report's property language <--- This is the answer to all your problems, don't ask me why it just works!!!