# Days function working in Jaspersoft Studio but not with JasperReports library

Tags: function, date, jasper-reports, expression

I have few reports which are using the built-in function DAYS(DATE1, DATE2) to calculate number of days between two dates.

My expression is `(DAYS(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse($F{DATE_DEBUT_ABSENCE}),new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse($V{date_fin_sejour}))+1).`

It's working well and without error on Jaspersoft studio 6.4.0 but when i try to generate the same report with JasperReports 6.2.0 i have an error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: DAYS(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse($F{DATE_DEBUT_ABSENCE_1}),new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse($V{date_de_fin_absence}))+1 
- UUID : D22C5C66-1B4F-4DF4-BD44-1E639D1F5197 
com.mysoftware.core.shared.exception.SysException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: DAYS(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse($F{DATE_DEBUT_ABSENCE_1}),new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse($V{date_de_fin_absence}))+1 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1706.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) 
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.instantiate(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:1110) 
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:682) 
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readObject(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:592) 
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader$ValueReader$8.readValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:149) 
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:434) 
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:312) 
at com.mysoftware.core.server.service.RemoteServiceDispatcher.processCall(RemoteServiceDispatcher.java:64) 
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373) 
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) 
at com.mysoftware.core.server.servlet.filter.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:93) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333) 
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) 
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) 
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564) 
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254) 
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295) 
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

And the POM.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I use JAVA as a language for expressions

How that expression can work properly on Jaspersoft Studio and not on JasperReports?

Comment: What libs are at classpath? What is a full stack trace?

Comment: I have edited the post with full stack trace. For the libs in classpath, you need all the list of libs i'm using @AlexK?

Comment: Libraries related to using JasperReports. What is the language of report, Groovy?

Comment: Looks like duplicate: [JasperReports: CONCATENATE function not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19450214/876298)

Comment: I have edited the post with libs. I have also check inside jasperreports-functions-6.2.0.jar and there is a method called DAYS(object, object) inside DateTimeFunctions.class...

Comment: Add full stack trace, including Caused by ... lines.

Comment: Sorry @dada67 but this is the only stack trace i have access. I don't have full access to all environment to see more log

Comment: I will check the existence of jasperreports functions and joda time libs on production server and i will see if it's the root of the problem.

Comment: OK, i can't check directly on production server... But i've tried a test. I have made a small simple report with some of DateTime functions which are inside jasperreports-functions libs... And it's pretty weird... NOW(), DAY(), SECOND(), DATEVALUE() are OK and functionnal, but DAYS(), YEARS(), MONTHS() give me the error mentionned here...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone and especially @AlexK who make search about library.

The problem was not the missing of the jasperreports-functions libs but the missing of the joda-time library which is used by jasperreports-functions inside DAYS(), YEARS() and MONTHS() methods.
Adding https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases/download/v2.9.9/joda-time-2.9.9.jar solved my problem.